# Starting on AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

I found Automapper quite interesting from the concept. I however am trying to burn (or heat up) my fingers on it. Can somebody help me to start on this? I am yet to understand where from I can start for this. I shall like to write some code from scratch (and not use a sample of others) and then do it. A step by step hand-holding will be the most welcome help.

Comment: Is there some part of the [documentation](http://automapper.codeplex.com/documentation) you have troubles with understanding and you would like to ask about? Is there some specific problem you are trying to solve? What is your question here?

Comment: are the links broken/missing on the documentation page? Looks like the home page http://automapper.codeplex.com/ has the links workings.

Comment: I am not complaining about the documentation. But I wanted to understand the application of AutoMapper. Following the documentation did not give me enough boost to start on it.

Comment: The application is to convert between different incompatible types where casts wouldn't work. For example I am using it extensively in my ASP.NET MVC applications to convert between the models and the view models.

Comment: @Darin: I am quite clear of what AutoMapper does. I am already in such scenarios earlier and I used to write my own handler for this. Now I wish to use Automapper for the same. I am looking forward for some guidance to start on this.

Comment: @Kangkan, so maybe you could start by describing those scenarios so that we have a base for discussion here. Right now it's way too abstract all this. Describe some specific scenario you have, how did you solved it before AutoMapper and let's see how AutoMapper can help you improve your current code (or it can't improve it because it is probably not adapted to the scenario your are going to describe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Darin said, the first place to go is the home page of AutoMapper and the documentation. If you need something like a How To, I would suggest you this article: http://jasona.wordpress.com/2010/02/05/getting-started-with-automapper/ and here is an example how to map view models in ASp.Net MVC -> http://www.bengtbe.com/blog/post/2009/04/14/Using-AutoMapper-to-map-view-models-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

Hope that helps you a little bit ;-9

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have started off finally.